# How to update the data source of a dashboard in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a dashboard with some visualizations on it. Recently, we have a new data source that is a saved search, and we need to change the index pattern of the dashboard to the saved search.

This is my first time working with kibana. I'm considering changing the index pattern of each panel on the dashboards. But when I edit the reference of the visualization to the id of the saved search, the visualization could not open. Is there anyway to change the data source of a visualization?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that is possible. Read this [post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-switch-source-of-visualization-from-index-pattern-to-saved-search/208341/2?u=rabbit_br).

Comment: Yes. I give up. I just create new visualizations from scratch.